# FFMpeg -filter_complex to place a video in a window on a larger image with text

Tags: ffmpeg, video-editor

I'm trying to work out how to combine both features of the following in one -filter_complex statement in order to take an image, write some text on it, and then do an additive composite of a small video to an area of the image.  Every time I try to combine these two things it doesn't work!

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i mic720x1280.png -vf drawtext="fontfile=Montserrat-Bold.ttf: text='Hello': fontcolor=white: fontsize=44: box=1: boxcolor=black@0.5: boxborderw=10: x=(w-text_w)/2: y=100" -c:v libx264 -t 15 -pix_fmt yuv420p myvid.mp4
```

```
-vf "movie=waves5.mp4, scale=500:-1 [inner]; [in][inner] overlay=70:70 [out]"
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edited** to change to additive blend.

Use

`ffmpeg -loop 1 -i mic720x1280.png -i waves5.mp4 -filter_complex "color=0x000000@0,format=gbrap[bg];[0]format=gbrap,drawtext=fontfile=Montserrat-Bold.ttf: text='Hello': fontcolor=white: fontsize=44: box=1: boxcolor=black@0.5: boxborderw=10: x=(w-text_w)/2: y=100,setsar=1[img];[bg][img]scale2ref[bg][img];[bg]setsar=1[bg];[1]scale=500:-1,format=gbrap[vid];[bg][vid]overlay=70:70:format=rgb[vidbl];[vidbl][img]blend=all_mode=addition" -c:v libx264 -t 15 -pix_fmt yuv420p myvid.mp4`

Comment: Hi, thankyou so much, this is fantastic, however finally how do I make the last [img][vid] an  additive composite blend rather than a plain overlay?

Comment: (thanks for your wonderful help though :) )